# Python Trim Help Variable both in single and double bracket

Tags: python, scrapy, trim

My Scrapy codes returning me a text --

```
<img src="//d30v2pzvrfyzpo.cloudfront.net/uk/images/restaurants/65115.gif" itemprop="image" alt="Gourmet Sushi" width="100" height="100" onerror="this.onerror = null;this.src = '//dy3erx8o0a6nh.cloudfront.net/images/serp/serp_default_logo.svg';">
```

How to trim it from `src="//` to `"`.

I am very new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet. You can apply regexps to selectors:

```
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> txt = """<img src="//d30v2pzvrfyzpo.cloudfront.net/uk/images/restaurants/65115.gif" itemprop="image" alt="Gourmet Sushi" width="100" height="100" onerror="this.onerror = null;this.src = '//dy3erx8o0a6nh.cloudfront.net/images/serp/serp_default_logo.svg';">"""
>>> sel = Selector(text=txt)
>>> sel.re("src\s?=\s?['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"]")
[u'//d30v2pzvrfyzpo.cloudfront.net/uk/images/restaurants/65115.gif', u'//dy3erx8o0a6nh.cloudfront.net/images/serp/serp_default_logo.svg']
```

So, and then you can do `[response.urljoin(url) for url in sel.re("src\s?=\s?['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"]")]`

Comment: Please give me an example. I don't have any experience with css selectors.

Comment: Misunderstood your question, updated answer. Please, try it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use python [regexp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).
Here is an exemple from the python interpreter. Try it, and accept if it fits your need.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<img src="//d30v2pzvrfyzpo.cloudfront.net/uk/images/restaurants/65115.gif" itemprop="image" alt="Gourmet Sushi" width="100" height="100" onerror="this.onerror = null;this.src = \'//dy3erx8o0a6nh.cloudfront.net/images/serp/serp_default_logo.svg\';">'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'<img\s+src="//([^"]+)".*')
>>> for i in pattern.findall(s):
...     print(i)

d30v2pzvrfyzpo.cloudfront.net/uk/images/restaurants/65115.gif
```